# How to start a empty variable from a custom type?

Tags: scala

I've a class that contains a custom type in it; my goal is to add new students to this "DB".

```
class School {
    type DB = Map[Int, Seq[String]]

    def add(name: String, g: Int) = ??? // Should be Map(g -> Seq[name])
}
```

i've also created a companion object to keep track of my students.

```
object School {
    // val records: DB = ???
}
```

But how can i start a empty "DB" type on my `object`?

Comment: `private var records = Map.empty[String, Seq[String]]`?

Comment: Do you want to have a shared variable across all the object of school?

Comment: @RamanMishra yes, the "DB" should be a "in-memory" database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need DB to contain the type arguments (e.g. the code later can deduce the type itself and this is the **most common** case), you can use the collection companion object itself (which is a `Factory`)

```
val DB = Map
def add(name: String, g: Int) = DB(g -> Seq(name))
```

If you need DB to contain the type argument, you need to create a `Builder`:

```
val DB = Map.newBuilder[Int, Seq[String]]
def add(name: String, g: Int) = DB.addOne(g -> Seq(name)).result() //Prior 2.13, please use `+=`
```

If you don't like Builder, you can use a little more verbose casting:

```
val DB = Map
type DB = Map[Int, Seq[String]]
def add(name: String, g: Int): DB = DB(g -> Seq(name)) //This ensures lower bound of covariant types
```

Comment: how can i add more than one name to the same map key? the "value" of the map is a seq, is there a `DB(g).append(name)`?

Comment: @RafaAcioly In that case you need to use a mutable Seq (collection.mutable.Seq) instead of the regular (immutable) and use the last solution in my answer. Then you can do `DB(g).append(name)`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your logic of adding the value if key already exist.

Please try this:

```
class School {

  def add(name: String, g: Int): records.type = {
    School.records += (g -> List(name))
  }
}

object School {
  val records: mutable.Map[Int, List[String]] = mutable.Map()

  def apply(): School = new School()
}

object Demo extends App {

  School().add("String", 1)
  School().add("String1", 2)
  School().add("String2", 3)
  School().add("String3", 2)
  School().add("String4", 1)

  print(School.records) // output: Map(2 -> List(String3), 1 -> List(String4), 3 -> List(String2))
}
```

Add Method with logic if key already exists:

```
  def add(name: String, g: Int): records.type = {
    School.records.isDefinedAt(g) match {
      case true => School.records += (g -> (School.records.getOrElse(g, List("")) ::: List(name)))

      case false => School.records += (g -> List(name))
    }
  }

//output for this add method Map(2 -> List(String1, String3), 1 -> List(String, String4), 3 -> List(String2))
```